# PHP Regex Not matching `\[`

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a regex to convert `\[#twitter:1234\]` into `[#twitter:1234]` i.e. unescape the square brackets for specific tags like Twitter, video, etc. I wrote up my expression and have tested it in [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) and [PHPLiveRegex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/) and it looks good but it still fails to get a match in my runtime. My actual implementation code is:

```
$content = preg_replace( "/\\\[#((?:twitter|video|instagram|cneembed):.*?)\\\]/i", "[#$1]", $content );
```

If anyone has any idea why the expression isn't working your guidance would be much appreciated. I'm generally pretty good at this stuff but I feel like I've gone blind on this one. I'm pretty certain the issue is how I'm escaping my backslashes since I can easily get the expression to match `[#twitter:1234\]` just not the leading slash. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that backslash is both an escape character for strings and also an escape character for regular expressions, so you need to double all the backslashes to get them to pass through to the regexp engine.

```
$content = preg_replace( "/\\\\\\[#((?:twitter|video|instagram|cneembed):.*?)\\\\\\]/i", "[#$1]", $content );
```

Comment: That worked thanks! I wish those online tools would cover that. Know if there are any tools that do? Also, would that also be the case with any delimiter or is it just because I'm using the `/` delimiter?

Comment: I don't know if any of the regex testers test with language syntax added on top. They're just for testing the regexp itself.

Comment: The delimiter is totally irrelevant to this problem. Although if you wanted to use backslash as a delimiter instead of forward slash, it would make it worse. Don't do that.

Comment: Hm yeah I assumed they actually fed into a PHP regex parser since they support things than JS regex just doesn't.

Comment: They do, but this issue is about PHP source code, it doesn't affect strings that come from an external source.

Comment: Although I don't think you can assume it's a PHP back-end. It could be Python, Perl, Java, etc. Regex101 lets you choose different flavors.